# Delete Row from DataGridView and Access Database, it`s delete my all database

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, datagridview, delete-row

In dataGrid delete the selected row, but my database is erased.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
                foreach (DataGridViewRow item in this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(item.Index);
                }

                con.Open();
                ad.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand("delete * from Animale", con);
                ds.Clear();
                ad.Fill(ds);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

                ad.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Missing a WHERE clause ? [WHERE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp)

Comment: use OleDbCommandBuilder. bind the the data through that.On Click of delete in DataGrid key events update the OledbAdapter you filled.
It will automatically delete those rows in DataBase.

Comment: I put "DELETE * from Animale WHERE Nr_Crt = @Nr_Crt", con); but "ad.Fill(ds);" and "ad.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();" it says me OleDbException was unhaldled

Comment: What as the exception? What was the exception message? Was it something about invalid query/parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you still want to do this using a query then you will need a WHERE clause in your delete statement.

To put you on the right path

```
            foreach (DataGridViewRow item in this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(item.Index);

                con.Open();
                ad.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand("delete * from Animale where id = " + item.id.ToString, con);
            }
```

but you should really use parameters